# Tcl calling numbered variable

Tags: tcl

In Tcl, I assigned values to numbered variables in a loop. 
how can I call these variables in another loop

```
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    set Col$colNum 0
}
```

```
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    puts "$Col$colNum"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in the same namespace, then you can use `set` in this way:

```
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    set Col$colNum 0
}   
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    puts [set Col$colNum]
}
```

---

Usually though, you may want to avoid doing it that way and use `array`s instead:

```
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    set Col($colNum) 0
}   
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    puts $Col($colNum)
}
```

Or use [`upvar`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm) to create an alias (I'm using `upvar` to the global namespace, `#0`, in the below example):

```
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    set Col$colNum 0
}   
for {set colNum 1} {$colNum < 37} {incr colNum} {
    upvar #0 Col$colNum currentCol
    puts $currentCol
}
```